# Bind ngStyle to a dynamic ElementRef of a directive

Tags: angular, directive

I develop a directive to add dynamically an elementRef to the current Element.
Is it possible to bind ngStyle directive to the dynamically created elementRef.

```
  dynamicElementStyle: { [key: string]: string; };

  constructor(private _element: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostListener('mouseover') onHover() {
    this.dynamicElementStyle.background-color = "red";
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onHover() {
    this.dynamicElementStyle.background-color = "green";
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    const dynamicElement = this._renderer.createElement('div');
    /* How to bind dynamicElementStyle to this dynamicElement */   
    this._renderer.appendChild(this._element.nativeElement, dynamicElement);
  }
```

I won't use Renderer2.setStyle() to apply style but use an object. It could be ngStyle as well as ngClass, ngIf etc....